# how to make one CustomScrollView for all pages

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a main page that, depending on the model, displays inside **CustomScrollView** **slivers** other pages.

Example:

```
CustomScrollView(
  physics: _bouncingScrollPhysics,
  controller: _scrollController,
  slivers: <Widget>[
    _pages[_selectedTab]
  ],
),
```

I do not want to duplicate `CustomScrollView` on each page with the controller and physics, so this solution seemed practical to me. But I encountered such a problem, if the page class returns, for example, one `SliverList`, then everything is ok, but what if the class needs to return more than one?

```
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return SliverList() //OK
 }

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return ...[
     SliverList(),
     SliverList()
   ]; // NOT OK
}
```

Comment: What do you mean under `SliverList`? The list of widgets for `slivers` property of `CustomScrollView`? Why don't to combine few `SliverLists` to single `SliverList`? `build` can return `only` single widget.

Comment: return ` ...[SliverList(),
     SliverList()
   ]` will expand the list which will not be a widget object. so the return type does not match with object returned.

Comment: I know that you cannot return `list <Widget>`, which is why I asked the question, are there any options? As for the merge ok, but what if you need to return `SliverAppBar`, `SliverList (delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate)`, `SliverList (delegate: SliverChildListDelegate)`. how then to be? I want to make one `CustomScrollView` for all pages, but not duplicate it for each

Answer (score 0):

Create class for store of sliver information

```
class SliverListInfo {
  final SliverAppBar sliverList;
  final SliverList sliverAppBar;
  SliverListInfo(this.sliverAppBar, this.sliverList);
}
```

Inside of `State` class of your `StatefullWidget` where you want to use `CustomScrollView`

```
class _SliverTestState extends State<SliverTest> {
  /// Selected tab pane
  int _selectedTab;

  /// List of sliver information
  final sliverLists = <SliverListInfo>[];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // Populate items
    sliverLists.add(SliverListInfo(SliverAppBar(...),
      SliverList(delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate),
    )); // page 1
    sliverLists.add(SliverListInfo(SliverAppBar(...),
      SliverList(delegate: SliverChildListDelegate),
    )); // page 2
    ...
  }

  @override
  void build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomScrollView(
      physics: _bouncingScrollPhysics,
      controller: _scrollController,
      slivers: sliverLists[_selectedTab],
    );
  }
}
```

P.S. Widget can be created as any other objects. `build` function is only used when widget is embedded into the widget tree to visuaalize it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer and time taken, this is a working option, only now there is another problem, you have to put all the pages on one page .. Ideally we need pages that inherit `Stateless / full / Widget`, we may need the same controller for a specific page and other logic, and sculpting everything on one page is a bad idea. But thanks to you, I solved this problem in the right way. In the end, I just made one shared page that accepts `list <Widget>` parameters. Now all pages simply return this and pass parameters, a kind of mixins

Comment: It seems I don't understand what do you mean. You asked how to use one `CustomScrollView` for all pages. So the idea is create a `host` (main) page that will contains `CustomScrollView` and initialize collection of sliver infos which will be displayed in this `host` page. I.e. you initialize colleciton `red app bar` for 1st tab, `green app bar` for 2nd tab. So when `_selectedTab` will be changed `CustomScrollView` will display corresponding widgets from your collection. 
P.S. Maybe I have no enough information about what you want... :) Hope this all help.s